# Multiple instances of featherlight iframe - not triggering

Tags: wordpress, loops, multiple-instances, featherlight.js

Fighting an issue on a kiosk project and using Featherlight iframe. It's a Hall of Fame project - if loaded on 1080px wide by 1920px tall (Chrome Developer Tools works great, but has to load fresh (clear cache), as we're creating a cookie for the resolution check to test against), then the project loads the kiosk version theme.

http://dev.demo38.com/owu/hall-of-fame/

We're listing the Hall of Fame members, pulled from a WordPress custom post type, and filtered with Isotope. The first time opening a Hall of Fame member's info in Featherlight lightbox from the Hall of Fame list, it works great, however, next attempts don't fire. Not getting any console errors.

Any thoughts on getting Featherlight to work with multiple instances?

This is the code from within the WordPress loop

```
<a class="anti-link-scroll" href="<?php the_permalink($post_object->ID); ?>" data-featherlight="iframe" data-featherlight-iframe-height="1080">

                    <span class="full-name"><span class="name"><?php the_field('last_name'); ?></span>, <?php the_field('first_name'); ?></span>

                </a>
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Your page has no featherlights. `$('[data-featherlight]').length // => 0`

Answer (score 0):

Featherlight handles multiple instances without a problem. The [gallery](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/gallery.html) example has two separate galleries, for example.

As always when trying to understand an issue, making a minimal example helps tremendously.